# Can grep show only words that match search pattern?

Tags: grep

Is there a way to make grep output "words" from files that match the search expression?

If I want to find all the instances of, say, "th" in a number of files, I can do:

```bash
grep "th" *
```

but the output will be something like (bold is by me);

```
some-text-file : the cat sat on the mat  
some-other-text-file : the quick brown fox  
yet-another-text-file : i hope this explains it thoroughly
```

What I want it to output, using the same search, is:

```
the
the
the
this
thoroughly
```

Is this possible using grep? Or using another combination of tools?

Comment: Is there a way one can print those matched words without changing the lines. Rather the matched string should remain in the same line?

Comment: tac file.log | grep "In msg::" | grep -oh "templateId=.*, temp"

Answer (score 1416):

Try `grep -o`:

```bash
grep -oh "\w*th\w*" *
```

Edit: matching from Phil's comment.

From [the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

```
-h, --no-filename
    Suppress the prefixing of file names on output. This is the default
    when there is only  one  file  (or only standard input) to search.
-o, --only-matching
    Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
    with each such part on a separate output line.
```

Comment: @user181548, The grep -o option works only for GNU grep. So if you are not using GNU grep, it might not work for you.

Comment: @A-B-B It depends if you want to display the name of the matched file or not.  I'm not sure under what conditions it does and doesn't display, but I do know that when I used grep across a number of directories it did display the full file path for all matched files, whereas with -h it just displayed the matched words without any specification about which file it is.  So, to match the original question, I think it is necessary in certain circumstances.

Comment: I needed an explanation for what `"\w*th\w*" *` means, so I figured I'd post. `\w` is [_[:alnum:]], so this matches basically any "word" that contains 'th' (since `\w` doesn't include space). The * after the quoted section is a glob for which files (i.e., matching all files in this directory)

Comment: `\w` is not generally portable to `grep -E`; for proper portability, use the POSIX character class name `[[:alnum:]]` instead (or `[_[:alnum:]]` if you really want the underscore, too; or try `grep -P` if your platform has that).

Comment: @A-B-B Given the desired output shown by the OP the `-h` is entirely necessary I would say.. ?

Comment: Much better than `abk`.

Comment: -o only gives me exactly what I searched for, I need the whole line. Wtf? It's like trying to work with a genie that takes everything too literally.

Comment: tac file.log | grep "In msg::" | grep -oh "templateId=.*, temp"

Answer (score 112):

**Cross distribution safe answer (including windows minGW?)**

```bash
grep -h "[[:alpha:]]*th[[:alpha:]]*" 'filename' | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -h "[[:alpha:]]*th[[:alpha:]]*"
```

If you're using older versions of grep (like 2.4.2) which do not include the -o option, then use the above. Else use the simpler to maintain version below.

**Linux cross distribution safe answer**

```bash
grep -oh "[[:alpha:]]*th[[:alpha:]]*" 'filename'
```

To summarize: `-oh` outputs the regular expression matches to the file content (and not its filename), just like how you would expect a regular expression to work in vim/etc... What word or regular expression you would be searching for then, is up to you! As long as you remain with POSIX and not perl syntax (refer below)

[More from the manual for grep](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=grep)

```
-o      Print each match, but only the match, not the entire line.
-h      Never print filename headers (i.e. filenames) with output lines.
-w      The expression is searched for as a word (as if surrounded by
         `[[:<:]]' and `[[:>:]]';
```

---

**The reason why the original answer does not work for everyone**

The usage of `\w` varies from platform to platform, as it's an extended "perl" syntax. As such, those grep installations that are limited to work with POSIX character classes use `[[:alpha:]]` and not its perl equivalent of `\w`. [See the Wikipedia page on regular expression for more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes)

Ultimately, the POSIX answer above will be a lot more reliable regardless of platform (being the original) for grep

As for support of grep without -o option, the first grep outputs the relevant lines, the tr splits the spaces to new lines, the final grep filters only for the respective lines.

(PS: I know most platforms by now would have been patched for \w.... but there are always those that lag behind)

Credit for the "-o" workaround from @AdamRosenfield answer

Comment: What about -o only working in GNU grep (as ksinkar mentioned in a comment on the accepted answer)?

Comment: @Brilliand hmm, im having trouble finding a linux implementation that does not support '-o', i can look for a work around if i know which platform to check against.

Comment: @pico The `-o` option is not present in the windows grep that installs with the git package (minGW?):

`"c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\grep" --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.4.2`

Comment: @BrucePeterson i have added in AdamRosenfield workaround answer for -o : Help me check if the windows git includes tr / sed and its version. So i can check if this workaround works

Comment: @pico:  for GIT:  GNU sed version 4.2.1, tr (GNU textutils) 2.0

Comment: `-o` is not valid in linux git either

Comment: @CollinAnderson Your comment doesn't really make sense. GNU `grep` and thus pretty much every Linux box has `grep -o`; there is no `-o` option in Git itself, but many Windows victims install a `git`package which includes many Unix utilities, including a `grep` implementation.

Comment: @BrucePeterson If you genuinely have GNU `grep` 2.4.2 then it's frightfully old; the `-o` option was introduced in 2.5.1 [sometime in 2001](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/ChangeLog-2009#n1228)

Comment: @tripleee I meant `git grep`

Answer (score 69):

It's more simple than you think. Try this:

```bash
egrep -wo 'th.[a-z]*' filename.txt #### (Case Sensitive)

egrep -iwo 'th.[a-z]*' filename.txt  ### (Case Insensitive)
```

**Where,**

```
egrep: Grep will work with extended regular expression.
w    : Matches only word/words instead of substring.
o    : Display only matched pattern instead of whole line.
i    : If u want to ignore case sensitivity.
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything over the existing answers from 4+ years before.

Comment: @tripleee I found my approach is better and simple so I posted this.

Answer (score 52):

You could translate spaces to newlines and then grep, e.g.:

```bash
cat * | tr ' ' '\n' | grep th
```

Comment: no need cat. tr ' ' '\n' < file | grep th.   Slow for big files.

Comment: This didn't work. The output still contained the filename and the entire line from the file that contained the match.

Anyway, one of the other solutions offered worked.

Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @ghostdog74: good point, although if you have more than file, you'll need to use cat.  @Neil Baldwin: are you sure you typed it in right?  When there's only one input file (stdin in this case), grep doesn't print the filename.

Comment: @Adam - yes, sorry Adam, it does work with one file but not multiple.

Comment: @Neil Baldwin: just list all of your files as parameters to cat, it works fine with multiple files

Comment: @Adam - so where you've got 'file' in the example, I would just put 'file1 file2 file3' etc. ?

Comment: @ghostdog74 if the slow part is because of `tr`, he could do `grep` first, so `tr` would be applied only to matching lines: `grep th filename | tr ' ' '\n' | grep th`

Answer (score 43):

Just `awk`, no need combination of tools.

```
# awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^th/){print $i}}}' file
the
the
the
this
thoroughly
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question posed.

Answer (score 13):

grep command for only matching and perl

```bash
grep -o -P 'th.*? ' filename
```

Comment: What about display of only the matched group?

Comment: This doesn't work; it will only ever find `th` because you requested the shortest possible repetition of the wildcard.

Comment: @tripleee - it won't have that problem, because there's a space included at the end of the regex.  However, it will miss words that don't have spaces after them, e.g. at the ends of lines.

Answer (score 10):

```bash
cat *-text-file | grep -Eio "th[a-z]+"
```

Comment: or just grep -Eio "th[a-z]+" filename

Comment: Maybe see also [Useless use of `cat`?](/q/11710552)

Answer (score 10):

I was unsatisfied with awk's hard to remember syntax but I liked the idea of using one utility to do this.

It seems like ack (or ack-grep if you use Ubuntu) can do this easily:

```
# ack-grep -ho "\bth.*?\b" *

the
the
the
this
thoroughly
```

If you omit the -h flag you get:

```
# ack-grep -o "\bth.*?\b" *

some-other-text-file
1:the

some-text-file
1:the
the

yet-another-text-file
1:this
thoroughly
```

---

As a bonus, you can use the `--output` flag to do this for more complex searches with just about the easiest syntax I've found:

```
# echo "bug: 1, id: 5, time: 12/27/2010" > test-file
# ack-grep -ho "bug: (\d*), id: (\d*), time: (.*)" --output '$1, $2, $3' test-file

1, 5, 12/27/2010
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also try **pcregrep**. There is also a `-w` option in **grep**, but in some cases it doesn't work as expected.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep):

```
cat fruitlist.txt
apple
apples
pineapple
apple-
apple-fruit
fruit-apple

grep -w apple fruitlist.txt
apple
apple-
apple-fruit
fruit-apple
```

Answer (score 4):

To search all the words with start with "icon-" the following command works perfect. I am using [Ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) here which is similar to grep but with better options and nice formatting.

```
ack -oh --type=html "\w*icon-\w*" | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, looking for grep/pattern regex and the "matched pattern found" as output.

At the end I used egrep (same regex on grep -e or -G didn't give me the same result of egrep) with the option -o

so, I think that could be something similar to (I'm NOT a regex Master) :

```bash
egrep -o "the*|this{1}|thoroughly{1}" filename
```

Comment: The useless `{1}` quantifiers should be dropped. Or if you want to be consistent, `t{1}h{1}e{1}` etc.

Comment: can it print with the same line?

Answer (score -1):

You could pipe your grep output into Perl like this:

```bash
grep "th" * | perl -n -e'while(/(\w*th\w*)/g) {print "$1\n"}'
```

Comment: that won't give the correct result. also, if using Perl, no need to use grep. do everything in Perl.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, ghostdog74. I have changed it to print all the words on the line, not just the first.

Comment: like i said, grep is not necessary.   perl -n -e'while(/(\s+th\w*)/g) {print "$1\n"}' file

Comment: I don't think it's important here to avoid using grep.

Comment: up to you. i am just illustrating a point. If its not necessary, don't do it. that extra "|" will cost you one process more.

Comment: In Perl 5.10 or later:  perl -nE '@a = /(regexp)/ig; say join "\n", @a'

Answer (score -1):

```bash
grep --color -o -E "Begin.{0,}?End" file.txt
```

`?` - Match as few as possible until the `End`

Tested on macos terminal

Answer (score -2):

```
$ grep -w
```

*Excerpt from grep man page:*

**-w:** Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The test is that the matching substring  must  either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.

Comment: That will still print the entire line containing the match. It constrains the actual match so that `the` no longer matches e.g. "these" or "bathe".

Answer (score -2):

#### [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

Here are the example using `ripgrep`:

```bash
rg -o "(\w+)?th(\w+)?"
```

It'll match all words matching `th`.