# How to terminal output command pipe to input of grep and using regular expression?

Tags: regex, grep, pipe

I thought getting an IP address on OSX or Linux would be rather easy to learn how to use regular expression with grep, but it looks like I either have a syntax error or misunderstanding of what is required.

I know this regex is correct, although I know it may not be a valid IP address I'm not considering that at this point.

```
(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}
```

so I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

```
ifconfig | grep -e "(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

First, there is a difference between `-e` and `-E` : `-e` just says "the next thing is an expression", while `-E` says: "use extended regular expressions". Depending on the exact version of grep you are using, you need `-E` to get things to work properly.

Second, as was pointed out before, `-d` isn't recognized by all versions of grep.  I found that the following worked: since ip addresses are "conventional" numbers, we don't need anything more fancy than `[0-9]` to find them:

```
ifconfig | grep -E '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

No need to escape other characters (in my version of grep - using OSX 10.7.5)

Incidentally, when testing your regular expression you can consider using something like

```
echo "10.1.15.123" | grep -E '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

to confirm that your regex is working - regardless of the exact output of `ifconfig`. It breaks the problem into two smaller problems, which is usually a good strategy.

Comment: Can the matching group in the regex alone be printed?

Comment: @SGSVenkatesh please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1546711/1967396) and associated answers. If that doesn't suffice, consider asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

`\d` is not understood by grep, instead you could use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`. Unfortunately there are many dialects of regular expressions. You will also have to escape `{`, `}`, `(` and `)`. The following works for me

```
/sbin/ifconfig | grep -e "\([[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}"
```