# Return only the regex match, not the whole line

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have a multiline document from which I'm looking to extract a particular keyword and the word after that. It looks like this:

```
This is key word1 line 1.

This is line 2.

This is key word2 line 3.
```

If I use `egrep 'key [^s]+ '`, the output is:

```
This is key word1 line 1.

This is key word2 line 2.
```

However, I'd like the output to be the match only as opposed to the whole line, that is:

```
key word1

key word2
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Can grep show only words that match search pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[`grep(1)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) has a `-o` flag that outputs only the matching part of the line.  From the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep):

> ```
>   -o, --only-matching
>       Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
> ```

Your pattern isn't right to get the output you want, though.  Try:

```sh
$ egrep -o 'key \w+' file 
key word1
key word2
```