# Select only a part of string ("name=number" ) with sed

Tags: sed

I have something like

```
chr1 162724289 162724421 CAAAATGTTTATAAGGACAGCCTGCTCTCTCCCCTCAGTACAGGGCAGCTGCTTGCCTGTGAACCAGTAAACAGCTCTGTGGTTTCATGGTTGCTCCCTCTCTCCCCAACCCTCACCTCTCAAGGCTGGACT chr1 162724414 162724421 ID=exon:ENST00000367921.3:5;Parent=ENST00000367921.3;gene_id=ENSG00000162733.12;transcript_id=ENST00000367921.3;gene_type=protein_coding;gene_status=KNOWN;gene_name=DDR2;transcript_type=protein_coding;transcript_status=KNOWN;transcript_name=DDR2-002;exon_number=5;exon_id=ENSE00001165686.1;level=2;protein_id=ENSP00000356898.3;ccdsid=CCDS1241.1;havana_gene=OTTHUMG00000034423.4;havana_transcript=OTTHUMT00000097650.1;tag=basic,appris_principal,CCDS
```

I would like to extract only the `exon_number=5` from the 8th column. This is kind of a long one line command and, since I have other columns I want to keep, I guess that I cannot use `awk -F ';'`. I tried something like:

`sed -E 's/ ID=*\(exon_number=[0-9]\)* \1/'`

Desired output:

```
chr1 162724289 162724421 CAAAATGTTTATAAGGACAGCCTGCTCTCTCCCCTCAGTACAGGGCAGCTGCTTGCCTGTGAACCAGTAAACAGCTCTGTGGTTTCATGGTTGCTCCCTCTCTCCCCAACCCTCACCTCTCAAGGCTGGACT chr1 162724414 162724421 exon_number=5
```

Any advice would be great!
Thanks

Comment: `grep -Eo 'exon_number=[[:digit:]]+'`?

Comment: With `sed -E 's/.*\<(exon_number=[0-9]+).*/\1/'`, I can only extract [`exon_number=26`](https://ideone.com/GlEfR1). How come you need `7`?

Comment: Sorry @WiktorStribiżew it was a mistake. Actually is `exon_number=26`. I will edit the question.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminW. That should be a good answer if I only want to print this. But, since I have more data in other columns that I would like to keep this is not my best option. That's why I asked for `sed`

Comment: Why do you have `ID=` in your pattern?

Comment: Try [`sed -E 's/(.* )ID=[^[:space:]]*(exon_number=[0-9]+).*/\1\2/'`](https://ideone.com/jvjJAp)

Comment: I will cast a reopen vote since the question is not about `grep`ping a value from text, and [Egrep/Sed: return only the regex match, not the whole line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539494)  does not solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew! That solved my problem. Capturing the first part was something I didn't thought (I'm kind of newbie :P).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The duplicate isn't a correct duplicate any longer, that's right. I'd also argue that it was before the question was edited to change input, expected output and wording, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP changed the requirement so putting solution as per that only.

```
awk -F";" 'match($0,/exon_number=[0-9]+/){val=$1;sub(/ ID.*/,"",val);print val,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

---

Following simple `awk` may help you here.

```
awk 'match($0,/exon_number=[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case your Input_file is having always same kind of data then simply print it by field.

```
awk -F";" '{print $11}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13 for the answer. It's great but this kind of command prints me only this column and I would like to keep the rest. I guess I explained myself very badly. I updated my question with more information to make myself clearer.

Comment: @Tato14, building on this answer, what about `awk 'match($8,/exon_number=[0-9]+/){$8=substr($8,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file`? If you don't want to print, don't print. It's your script, after all, you can do what you like.

Comment: Hi @ghoti, thanks for the answer. I guess I make not myself clear again. In this case I found a good option in the comments.

Comment: @Tato14, try my EDIT solution and let me know on same then?

Comment: I'm not sure how `print $11` would achieve the "Desired output" you included in your question. But if this is the solution that you *want*, then perhaps you could update your question to match, so that future generations reading this are not confused by the mismatched Q and A.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`, you may match and remove exactly what you want:

```
sed -E 's/(.* )ID=[^[:space:]]*(exon_number=[0-9]+).*/\1\2/'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/jvjJAp)

**Explanation**

- `-E` - POSIX ERE syntax enabling option
- `(.* )ID=[^[:space:]]*(exon_number=[0-9]+).*` - a rege pattern matching:

  - `(.* )` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as many as possible, and then a space
  - `ID=[^[:space:]]*` - `ID=` and 0+ whitespace chars
  - `(exon_number=[0-9]+)` - `exon_number=` and 1 or more digits (Group 2)
  - `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\1\2` - the replacement pattern inserts the contents of Group 1 and 2 into the resulting string.