# Linux - Only find a pattern within a line, not the whole line

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I want to use a regex to find a pattern in a file. That pattern may be in the middle of a line, but I don't want the whole line. I tried `grep -a pattern file` but this returns the entire line that contains the regex. The following is an example of what I'm trying to do. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Example:

Input: `AAAAAAAAAAAAAXxXxXxXxBananasyYyYyYyYBBBBBBBCCCCCC`

Regex: `Xx.*yY`

Ouput: `XxXxXxXxBananasyYyYyYyY`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can grep show only words that match search pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you were close, you need the `-o` flag

```
grep -o 'Xx.*yY' <<<AAAAAAAAAAAAAXxXxXxXxBananasyYyYyYyYBBBBBBBCCCCCC
XxXxXxXxBananasyYyYyYyY
```

Comment: Note: The `-o` flag is nonstandard, although it exists on both BSD and GNU userland systems.

Comment: @JS웃 It's available on a freshly built FreeBSD 10 I have right here as well as OS X (Mavericks), which says `BSD` at the bottom of the `grep` manpage.

Comment: @kojiro Sorry my bad. I got confused with `-P` option. My apologies. I wrote `-o` option and was looking for `-P`.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-o` option to print just the part of the line that matches the regexp

```
grep -o pattern file
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `grep -o` (the simplest way), there are a couple of other options:

1. In `bash`, without relying on any particular implementation of `grep`:

   ```
   $ regex='Xx.*yY'
   $ [[ AAAAAAAAAAAAAXxXxXxXxBananasyYyYyYyYBBBBBBBCCCCCC =~ $regex ]]
   $ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
   XxXxXxXxBananasyYyYyYyY
   ```
2. Using `expr`, which is a little unwieldy (in part because the regular expression is implicitly anchored to the beginning of the string), but is defined by the POSIX standard so it should work on any POSIX platform, regardless of the shell used.

   ```
   $ expr AAAAAAAAAAAAAXxXxXxXxBananasyYyYyYyYBBBBBBBCCCCCC : '[^X]*\(Xx.*yY\)'
   XxXxXxXxBananasyYyYyYyY
   ```