# Extracting the pattern from the line

Tags: shell, design-patterns, extract, cat

How can I extract words which contains the pattern "a*rum*" from the following line:

```
Agarum anoestrum  alabastrum sun antirumor alarum antiserum ambulacrum antistrumatic Anatherum antistrumous androphorum antrum 4. foodstuff foody nonfood Aplectrum
```

So words like sun, 4., foody, nonfood should be removed.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1546711/2706918

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
echo "Agarum anoestrum sun" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep "arum"
```

`tr` is used to split the input string in one word per line, since grep operates on a per-line basis and would display the whole line.
If you want the output to be in one line again, use:

```
echo "Agarum anoestrum sun" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep "arum" | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -Eo`:

```
grep -Eo 'a[[:alnum:]]*rum' file
arum
anoestrum
alabastrum
antirum
alarum
antiserum
ambulacrum
antistrum
atherum
antistrum
androphorum
antrum
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo Agarum anoestrum alabastrum sun antirumor alarum antiserum ambulacrum antistrumatic Anatherum antistrumous androphorum antrum 4. foodstuff foody nonfood Aplectrum | awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) { if (match($i, "[aA][[:alnum:]]*[rR][uU][mM]") != 0) { printf ("%s ", $i) }} print}'
```