# Using grep how to get whole word with numeric digits only the word in line

Tags: linux, grep

I facing an issue when I use this command

```
"grep  RTB4"
```

The output is:

```
192.168.1.1   RTB4-NODE-1
```

I only have to get `RTB4-NODE-1` in output.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can grep show only words that match search pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "word" you mean anything not interrupted by spaces:

```
grep RTB4 | tr ' ' '\n' | grep RTB4
```

You can add more characters to the `tr` command if you need to split on other forms of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you really want is:

```
awk '$NF~/RTB4/{print $NF}' file
```

so it only looks for the regexp in and prints the last space-separated field on each line.

Answer (score 0):

This `gnu awk` (gnu due to multiple characters in RS) should do:

```
awk -v RS=" *" '/RTB4/'
```

eks:

```
echo "192.168.1.1   RTB4-NODE-1" | awk -v RS=" *" '/RTB4/'
RTB4-NODE-1
```