# Search for specific words and print only those words in a separate file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a `.gz` file on my Unix server.  I want to search for two words like `abc123` and `def456` from that file and if I have these words in the file, I want to print only those (only 2 words not entire line) words in a separate file.

Comment: i tried with grep command, but it is printing whole line from the file, but i want only those two words...not entire line which is having these words

Comment: I suggest you edit the question with the command you used that didn't return the results you want.  Someone will then be able to correct it for you.

Comment: You should really show the command(s) that you've tried, explaining why they don't do what you want.  Suppose the file wasn't compressed; what would you do to get the information you want from the non-compressed file?  How do you see the decompressed contents of a file without actually decompressing the file?  How do you combine these two operations?  You say 'Unix'; which variant of Unix?  Does it have GNU `grep` with the `-o` option?  What should happen if the words you're after occur more than once each in the file?  Does the order in which the words appear in the output matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
zcat f.xml.gz | awk '{\
{ \
if(index($0,str_1)) \
   cnt_1=1; \
if(index($0,str_2)) \
   cnt_2=1; \
if((cnt_1 + cnt_2) == 2) {\
   print str_1,str_2> "f_out.log"; exit;} \
} }' str_1="Keepout" str_2="LatLonList"
```

where

- "f.xml.gz" is the input file
- str_1 is the first word (your "abc123")
- str_2 is the second word (your "def456")
- "f_out.log" is the separate file in which the two words are written if found in the input file

Hope this helps.

Comment: All those backslashes are unnecessary unless you're careless enough to use a C shell derivative instead of a Bourne shell derivative as your main shell.  Sea shells belong on the sea shore, IMO.  And in a Bourne-shell derivative, those backslashes would break the script.  The opening `{ {` and matching closing `} }` is odd; what's the advantage of the double braces instead of just single braces?  Why did you decide to use 'Keepout' and 'LatLonList' instead of `abc123` and `def456`?

Comment: the above snippet is not working... if i give str_1 world then also it is printing world, even world word in not present in my file

Answer (score 0):

Your question has an answer [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern)

You can run this command to achieve what you want

```
gzcat <filename.zip> | grep -oh "<Search pattern>" *
```

for ex

```
gzcat <filename.zip> | grep -oh "abc123" *
```

I do not have zgrep installed but you can also try this

```
zgrep -oh "<Search pattern>" *` filename.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

Use `ripgrep`, it's written in [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_(programming_language)) therefore very efficient, especially for large files. For example:

```
rg -zo "abc123|def456" *.gz
```

> `-z`/`--search-zip` Search in compressed files (such as `gz`, `bz2`, `xz`, and `lzma`).
>
> `-o`/`--only-matching` Print only the matched parts of a matching line.

Answer (score 0):

#### `grep`/`zgrep`/`zegrep`

Use `zgrep` or `zegrep` to look for pattern in compressed files using their uncompressed contents (both GNU/Linux and BSD/Unix).

On Unix, you can also use `grep` (which is [BSD version](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep)) with `-Z`, including `-z` on macOS.

Few examples:

```
zgrep -E "abc123|def456" *.gz
zegrep "abc123|def456" **/*.gz
grep -z -e "abc123" -e "def456" *.gz # BSD/Unix only.
```

<sup>Note: When you've [globbing option enabled](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option), `**` checks the files recursively, otherwise use `-r`.</sup>

> `-R`/`-r`/`--recursive` Recursively search subdirectories listed.
>
> `-E`/`--extended-regexp` Interpret pattern as an extended regular expression (like `egrep`).
>
> `-Z` ([BSD](https://man.openbsd.org/grep)), `-z`/`--decompress` ([BSD/macOS](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html)) Force grep to behave as `zgrep`.