# list match word in shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix

For example, I type "cat XXX.cpp | grep ".png" "
it show in terminal:

```
(standard input):    infoSp = CCScale9Sprite::create("task_img_5.png");
(standard input):        const CCSize tempSize = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("bg_num.png")->getContentSize();
(standard input):            AHControlButton* pBtn = AHControlButton::create(CCScale9Sprite::create("bg_list_b.png"));
(standard input):            pBtn->setBackgroundSpriteForState(CCScale9Sprite::create( "bg_list_c.png"), CCControlStateHighlighted);
(standard input):            pBtn->setBackgroundSpriteForState(CCScale9Sprite::create( "bg_list_b.png"), CCControlStateDisabled);
```

But, I just need it list ".png" only, like:

```
"a.png"
"b.png"
"c.png"
```

Someone know that? please help me, thanks.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern

Comment: grep -oh "\".*png\"" works