# how to write a grep result of pipe into a file

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to save some simple info of images in a directory(like the image shown below):
[image]

But how can I write the **matched parts** into a file?
I have tried appending `>> img_info.txt` but it wrote the whole output instead of being selective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grep's option `-o` as described in [Can grep show only words that match search pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern).

Cited from the other answer:

```
-o, --only-matching
    Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
    with each such part on a separate output line.
```

Aside from that grep is probably not the best tool to search and extract strings. This is rather the job of `sed` or `awk`.