# Replace regex with captured group ONLY

Tags: regex, perl, sed, regex-group

I'm trying to understand why the following does not give me what I *think* (or want :)) should be returned:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*?)(Some text)?(.*)$/\2/' list_of_values
```

or Perl:

```
perl -lpe 's/^(.*?)(Some text)?(.*)$/$2/' list_of_values
```

So I want my result to be **just the `Some text`**, otherwise (meaning if there was nothing captured in `$2`) then it should just be EMPTY.

I did notice that with **perl** it *does* work if `Some text` is at the start of the line/string (which baffles me...). (Also noticed that removing `^` and `$` has no effect)

Basically, I'm trying to get what `grep` would return with the `--only-matching` option as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1546711/3299282). Only I want/need to use sub/replace in the regex.

**EDITED** (added sample data)

Sample input:

```
$ cat -n list_of_values
     1  Black
     2  Blue
     3  Brown
     4  Dial Color
     5  Fabric
     6  Leather and Some text after that ....
     7  Pearl Color
     8  Stainless Steel
     9  White
    10  White Mother-of-Pearl Some text stuff
```

Desired output:

```
$ perl -ple '$_ = /(Some text)/ ? $1 : ""' list_of_values | cat -n
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6  Some text
     7
     8
     9
    10  Some text
```

Comment: Sed doesn't know non-greedy matching with `.*?`.

Comment: Can you give some sample of desired input/output?

Comment: Why does this have a Perl tag? Are you looking for a Perl alternative solution?

Comment: Actually, I'm just using perl as a tool to understand how to get this to work in a different tool that supports (Java) Regex where the `substitute` and `replace` are "coded" in text boxed (yikes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658333/grep-p-no-longer-works-how-can-i-rewrite-my-searches/16658690) shows how to duplicate `grep -o` using Perl.

---

You're asking why applying `s/^(.*?)(Some text)?(.*)$/$2/` again

```
foo Some text bar
012345678901234567
```

results in just a empty string instead of

```
Some text
```

Well,

- At position 0, `^` matches 0 characters.
- At position 0, `(.*?)` matches 0 characters.
- At position 0, `(Some text)?` matches 0 characters.
- At position 0, `(.*)` matches 17 characters.
- At position 17, `$` matches 0 characters.
- Match succeeds.

You could use

```perl
s{^ .*? (?: (Some[ ]text) .* | $ )}{ $1 // "" }xse;
```

or

```perl
s{^ .*? (?: (Some[ ]text) .* | $ )}{$1}xs;     # Warns if warnings are on.
```

Far simpler:

```perl
$_ = /Some text/ ? $& : "";
```

---

I question your use of `-p`. Are you sure you want a line of output for each line of input? It seems to me you'd rather have

```bash
perl -nle'print $& if /Some text/'
```

Comment: The answer/trick was about making proper use of non-capturing groups, that did it for me! Thanks. I just wonder why are you using the `/s` modifier ?

Comment: Why would I want to check if the characters are newlines?