# How can I capture all numbers in a string using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I tried to use `sed` to capture numbers in a string with following script:

```
echo '["770001,德邦优化混合","750005,安信平稳增长混合发起A"]' | sed -n 's/.*"\(\d{6}\),/\1/p'
```

My expectation is echo

```
770001
750005
```

While nothing output. Why?

Comment: sed doesn't support \d.. use [0-9] instead.. `{}` needs to be escaped as well.. and there is greedy issue as well.. I feel `grep -o '[0-9]\{6\}'` is better suited here..

Comment: @Sundeep thanks for your answer, that works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can grep show only words that match search pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern)

Comment: @Sundeep, A little different i think, I was trying to use `sed` to get all capture groups

Comment: well you said my grep solution worked.. often cli questions will get answers with totally different tools.. if you want answer with sed only, then I'll retract my vote..

Answer (score 1):

In case you are ok with `awk` then following `awk` may help you in same. Since I have old version of `awk` so I am using `--re-interval` if you have newer version of `awk` then you may not need it.

```
echo '["770001,德邦优化混合","750005,安信平稳增长混合发起A"]' |
awk --re-interval '{while(match($0,/[0-9]{6}/)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)}}'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
770001
750005
```