# Retrieve only the matching pattern of a list in another list with grep

Tags: grep

I have this kind of files:

**file1 :**

```
TMCS09g1008676.1
MAMBO.3.3.2.1
TMCS09g1008678.1
TMCS09g1008678.2
CSH.1.2
TMCS09g1008681.3
TMCS09g1008682.1
TMCS09g1008683
```

**file2:**

```
TMCS09g1008676
MAMBO.3.3.2
TMCS09g1008678
TMCS09g1008679
CSH.1
TMCS09g1008681
TMCS09g1008682
TMCS09g1008683
```

What I want to do is to retrieve only the matching part of file 2 in file 1. Basically only the "red" part of the terminal showing the matching with the command `grep -w -F -f file2 file1`
Is there a way to achieve this?
thanks in advance

Comment: The expected result of your command is `TMCS09g1008683`, right? What's wrong with that?

Comment: add your expected output for clarity...  may be you are looking for `-o` option?

Comment: Thanks! it was indeed what i was searching for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can grep show only words that match search pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern)