# Extract whole word by searching prefix

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a File Pattern Like

> Listing "/MySqlDB-Backup"... DONE
>
> [F] 202818 MySql-DataBase-2020-09-26_111645.zip
>
> [F] 211436 MySql-DataBase-2020-10-05_063303.zip

How can I extract Only the Name of the files Like

> MySql-DataBase-2020-09-26_111645.zip
>
> MySql-DataBase-2020-10-05_063303.zip

Any Grep/awk/sed command which can work?

I tried using `grep -w "MySql-DataBase"`
The Output was :

```
MySql-Database
MySql-Database
MySql-Database
```

I want to use it in Bash

Comment: what commands have you already tried?

Comment: Before asking here, you need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is this question for CLI or PHP?

Comment: Could you confirm "[F] 202818 MySql-DataBase-2020-09-26_111645.ziz" on line number 2 is end with ".ziz" or ".zip", please edit post if needed.

Comment: I tried using grep -w 

I tried to search but the result was only "MySql-DataBase" nothing else


I need to use it in bash script

I am sorry it was a typing mistake its .zip

Comment: Try with `grep -o "[^ ]*\.zip"` or `grep "\[F\]" file_name | awk '{print $3}'`. Good luck

Comment: It worked with this command 
grep -o "[^ ]*\.zip"              Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can grep show only words that match search pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern)